# android http request giving null exception

Tags: android, androidhttpclient

In My Android project I want to store person data.
The basic is, after fill up person details form,when press **enter** it will connect to server and from server data will store.

So, I have:

```
 private void serverSignup(final Person suf) {
        new AsyncTask<Person, Void, String>() {
            @Override
            protected String doInBackground(Person... params) {
                String serverResponse = "";

    try {
         serverResponse = mServerAuth.userSignup(suf.getName(),
          suf.getCountry(),suf.getDate(), suf.getEmail());

          } catch (Exception e) {
          Log.e("ErrorMessage", TAG + " > Signup access server error: " + 
          e.getMessage());  **I am getting this section as null

            }
                return serverResponse;
            }

            @Override
            protected void onPostExecute(String serverResponse) {
            finish();

            }
        }.execute();
    }
```

and **mServerAuth** code is:

```
    public String userSignup(String name, String country,
 String date, String email) throws Exception {

            String url = "http://localhost:8080/SpringMVCHibernate/person/add";
            Person suf = new Person(name, country, date, email);
            List<NameValuePair> pairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>(1);
            pairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("suf", new Gson().toJson(suf)));

            DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
            HttpEntity requestEntity = new UrlEncodedFormEntity(pairs);
            HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(url);
            httpPost.setEntity(requestEntity);


            try {

            HttpResponse response = httpClient.execute(httpPost);
            HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();

            } catch (IOException ioe) {

            Log.e("Error", TAG + " > 
            IOEException during the POST response: " + ioe.getMessage());
            }

            return null;
        }}
```

To access this code I am getting error:

`Signup access server error:` **null**
why the value is null??Is it not connecting to the server??

Comment: Did you add the right permission in your Manifest.xml

Comment: @Preeti: use HTTPUrlConnection for Webservice request.

Comment: @kevz:  ok,But why I have to use "HTTPUrlConnection"? DefaultHttpClient not supports???

Comment: @Preeti: Yep its deprecated in new Apis in Android.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well u shdn't use deprecated apis in Android. Below is the code using HTTPUrlConnection api. Hope it help to serve ur purpose.

```
new AsyncTask < Person, Void, String > () {

String LOGIN_URL = "http://localhost:8080/SpringMVCHibernate/person/add";
HttpURLConnection conn;
DataOutputStream wr;
String responseCode = "-1";
URL url;

@Override
protected String doInBackground(String...params) {

    try {

        url = new URL(LOGIN_URL);
        conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
        conn.setDoOutput(true);
        conn.setRequestMethod("POST");
        conn.connect();


        Person suf = new Person(name, country, date, email);
        String strSuf = new Gson().toJson(suf);

        wr = new DataOutputStream(conn.getOutputStream());
        wr.writeBytes(strSuf);
        wr.close();

        responseCode = conn.getResponseCode();

        return responseCode;

    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } finally() {
        conn.disconnect();
    }

    return responseCode;
}

@Override
protected void onPostExecute(String responseCode) {

    if (!responseCode.equals("-1"))
        Toast.makeText(mContext, "Stored data successfully", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    else
        Toast.makeText(mContext, "failed to store data", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}

}.execute();
```

Comment: @Preeti: Check the answer using HTTPUrlConnection.

Answer (score 0):

From `HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();`
your getting the entity object but your not reading the data, simple you are returning the null.

You need to get the response like this

```
HttpResponse httpresponse = httpclient.execute(httppost);
String  response=EntityUtils.toString(httpresponse.getEntity());
```

Then you need to return the "response" string.

At the same time check the url also its working or not?

Comment: I have done this also,But still same error.. In my connection,I am using Internet from  wifi ,I connect my PC through "usb teathering"..In the localhost I Put computer IP address..